# PyVisa-py backend

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi2

I have an error appeared on installing pyvisa-py pn on raspberry pi2, which is

> ImportError: cannot import name rname

after I run command

```
rm = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
```

Here is the message given by interrupter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 1477, in new
visa_library = open_visa_library(visa_library)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 1446, in open_visa_library
cls = get_wrapper_class(wrapper)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 1426, in get_wrapper_class
pkg = import(pkgname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa-py/init.py", line 26, in 
from .highlevel import PyVisaLibrary
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa-py/highlevel.py", line 20, in 
from pyvisa import constants, errors, highlevel, rname
ImportError: cannot import name rname
```

Also, Here is the here's what python -m visa info returns :

```
Machine Details:
Platform ID: Linux-3.18.11-v7+-armv7l-with-debian-7.8
Processor: 
Python:
Implementation: CPython
Executable: /usr/bin/python
Version: 2.7.3
Compiler: GCC 4.6.3
Bits: 32bit
Build: Mar 18 2014 05:13:23 (#default)
Unicode: UCS4
PyVISA Version: 1.6.3
Backends:
ni:
Version: 1.6.3 (bundled with PyVISA)
Binary library: Not found
py:
Could not instantiate backend
-> cannot import name rname
sim:
Does not provide debug info
```

Could anyone help me solve it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/hgrecco/pyvisa/issues/149 explains how to fix this. In short, you seem to have a pyvisa-py that requires a newer (development) version of pyvisa.